# Community Builder not working in clean Joomla 3.5 installation (PHP7)

Tags: php, joomla, php-7, joomla-community-builder

I've been using Community Builder (CB) on a Joomla 2.5 website for a while without any problems. Yesterday I tried to install CB v2.0.13 on a clean Joomla 3.5 installation. The actual installation process finishes without any errors, but when I try to access any backend functionality of CB, i.e. the user management, the following error occurs:

> Argument 1 passed to CBLib\Session\SessionState::__construct() must implement interface CBLib\Session\SessionInterface, null given

For development, I am using the Bitnami WAMP stack with PHP7. According to https://www.joomlapolis.com/news/18532-cb-2013-ready-for-joomla-35-and-php-70 CB 2.0.13 supports both, PHP7 & Joomla 3.5.

Has anybody come across the same issue and got an idea how to make CB work in my setup?

Comment: You may want to contact the CB team and ask if it's compatible with PHP 7. On a side note, please update to Joomla 3.5 RC-3, as we're not on beta anymore

Comment: You would have to find the actual line throwing the error, which is quite clear by the way. An objects expects a specific type to be constructed and instead it receives a null (ie no object). find where the error is thrown and make sur to pass the right object to the constructor.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are pointing at. You're right, it's quite clear what is causing the exception to be thrown. As for why the object passed into the constructor is null, I have no idea because I have no control over the code. @Lodder: I am on RC-3 now, thanks for the hint. The issue still persists though.

Comment: @JanWendland - Please notify the CB team. If this is a bug and that don't know about it, they can't fix it :)

Comment: @Lodder I contacted them on Facebook (as you need pro membership to open a ticket on their website) and they read my message but neither replied nor took any action so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community Builder v2.0.14 was just released and resolves my issue. It's working like a charme now. More information on the update: https://www.joomlapolis.com/news/18543-joomla-35-and-community-builder-2014-released